# how to download pictures and videos from instagram from post's link

Tags: android, download, instagram

I creating a Instagram download android  app. how to i download pictures and videos from Instagram by copy share URL in android? or how to i get the download URL of pictures and videos in Instagram exactly?
Thanks.

Comment: You did the App, you explain us.

Comment: have you found the solution? Please share it

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you mean share URL such `https://www.instagram.com/p/-vSJNUDKKD/` then it's easy, just add `?__a=1` to URL like `https://www.instagram.com/p/-vSJNUDKKD/?__a=1` and you'll receive JSON contains image download address.

Comment: Thanks.this is a correct answer.How to i download user profile picture in full-size image by username in instagram? @ilyapt

Comment: @SaeidM try to use `https://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1` there you'll see profile picture but i'm not sure about full-size.

Comment: Hi. When i download json from my code it receive full html page content (by html tags). How to i downlaod only json data from url ( such https://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1)? thanks. @ilyapt

Comment: Thank's, is correct...

Comment: I am getting the full html page content if i make a get request using this url.

Comment: what i have to do for download the video

Comment: how can i get the video duration

Comment: but how to download video from response   see https://textuploader.com/1dsjk

Comment: @ilyapt Yoy are awesome man.

Comment: can we get multiple page data using this https://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1 url ?

Comment: 1. Right click on page and click on "View Page Source". It will open a new tab
2. Search for URL like.. https://www.instagram.com/p/-vSJNUDKKD
3. change url to https://www.instagram.com/p/-vSJNUDKKD?__a=1 by adding ?__a=1
4. You will get a json object.. in json object search for "display_url"
5. Value of display_url is the URL of picture that you want to download.

Comment: @RaviSuryawanshi here we get only latest 12 timeline media, any way to get more ?

Comment: Hi, @ilyapt How i can download my follower post (Private account post)
I am make the below type of link like..
URL : https://www.instagram.com/p/CdI6vHQD-4q/?i__a=1 but i am getting html response so plz help me.

Comment: this solution not work anymore...