# How to receive data from Instagram programmatically android

Tags: android, android-studio, url, instagram, html-parsing

By referring to existing blogs like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42995770/15581034)
I got to know it can be done adding `?__a=1` as a extension to link then it will return a
jsonObject, sure it does but only in browser.

I tried this(Kotlin)

```
        Thread {
            var link = "https://www.instagram.com/reel/CZBE3OIJ4vB/?__a=1"
            Log.d(tag, "Requesting URL: $link")
            val reader =
                BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(URL(link).openStream(), "UTF-8"))
            var sResponse: String?
            var s = StringBuilder()

            while (reader.readLine().also { sResponse = it } != null) {
                s = s.append(sResponse)
            }
            Log.d(tag, "Returned Data  :${s.toString()}")
        }.start()
```

but it returns `<!DOCTYPE html>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" class="no-js not-logged-in client-root touch">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">...
```

What should I do to receive jsonObject just like received browser

Answer (score -1):

using the /?__a=1 at the end of the url you can get the user's JSON. Unfortunately this cannot be used frequently because Instagram is able to know. When your IP address goes into the Instagram blacklist you won't be able to get the JSON.
You immediately notice when your IP address is in the blacklist because the url replies with an html page that corresponds to the Instagram login page.
There are 2 ways to solve this problem:
-1 Use Instagram API;
-2 Change the IP address of the machine making the request each time;

I hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your response, How can I will use Instagram api
Can you help me?

Comment: For use instagram api you must add your application on Facebook developer console. Then chose the instagram api wich you need. Graph or basic display. The first request is for token. The token is valid for 1 hour, and with the next token request you can extend the tokek duration about 60 days.